# Drag and drop issue firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, firefox-os

When I click an image inside a div and try to drag only the image is dragged not the whole div.It creates an out of memory exception when I drop that inside a new div

html:

```
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>B</header>
        <p>
        Put me
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>C</header>
        <p>
        right
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>D</header>
        <p>
        into
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>E</header>
        <p>
        the
        </p>
    </div>
```

script:

```
  (function () {
        var id_ = 'boxes-example';
        var boxes_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .box');
        var dragSrcEl_ = null;

        this.handleDragStart = function (e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

            dragSrcEl_ = this;

            this.style.opacity = '0.5';

            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.addClassName('moving');
        };

        this.handleDragOver = function (e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
            }

            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnter = function (e) {
            this.addClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDragLeave = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is previous target element.

            this.removeClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDrop = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is current target element.

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
            }

            // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same box we're dragging.
            if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
                dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnd = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.style.opacity = '1';

            [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
                box.removeClassName('over');
                box.removeClassName('moving');
            });
        };

        [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
            box.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable boxes to be draggable.
            box.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
            box.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
        });
    })();
```

This is a sample basic html5 drag and drop code.You can take any drag and drop code and check this issue

Comment: some code to look at would help in pointing out where you've gone wrong

Comment: We definitely need to see your code, a 'working' example (as in, representative of your project) would be helpful.
How are you applying your handlers?

Comment: done @ Jaromanda X @ Ben Philipp

Answer (score 0):

The Image is draggable by default and seems to take precedence over its parent draggable. It works for me on FireFox by explicitly setting the img draggable to false

```
<img src="drag icon.png" draggable="false"  width="16" height="16"/>
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn4uo8sw/1/) I set the first image to draggable to show the difference. If the first is dragged (B) the entire div is dragged, for the others, only the image is dragged. (didn't look at the other behaviour inside the drag events, purely if the entire div is dragged)

---

*edit*:  A more generic method, to disable dragging on all images:

```
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img') ,function(img){
     img.draggable=false;
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn4uo8sw/3/)